# How to parse a table in TXT

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I have a bunch of Log files (saved as .txt) that contain a 'table' at the end of each log that I need to parse.

What do I mean by 'table'?

```
            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :       332       332       332         0         0         0
Files :      1351      1087       264         0         0         0
Bytes :   1.621 g   1.222 g  408.39 m         0         0         0
```

I need to search each of these text files for any entries under the 'failed' header in the 'table'.

I am, at best, at an intermediate level with authoring and use of PowerShell but I know nothing about any other scripting languages.

How can this be done using PowerShell v. 5+?

I have searched online including StackOverflow but I think I may be using the wrong terminology for what I need to do.

Comment: So which part is it that you need help with? have you already accomplished the task of extracting this table from the files and you only need help parsing it?

Comment: Are you just parsing RoboCopy logs?

Comment: @ TheMadTechnician - Yes. I'm trying to parse Robo Copy logs.

 
@Santiago Squarzon - I'mm not at all sure how to get started, I wasn't sure if I would need to start with extracting it to a CSV or if it could be done from the txt format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear but assuming you have already accomplished the task of extracting those tables from your files, the following replacement pattern would work to convert the tables into CSVs then you can use `ConvertFrom-Csv` and treat them as objects. For instance, using the table in question:

```bash
$csv = @'
            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :       332       332       332         0         0         0
Files :      1351      1087       264         0         0         0
Bytes :   1.621 g   1.222 g  408.39 m         0         0         0
'@ -replace '(?: :)? {2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv -WA 0
```

This would result into the following array of objects:

```
H1    Total   Copied  Skipped  Mismatch FAILED Extras
--    -----   ------  -------  -------- ------ ------
Dirs  332     332     332      0        0      0
Files 1351    1087    264      0        0      0
Bytes 1.621 g 1.222 g 408.39 m 0        0      0
```

Then you can simply filter or select as with any array of objects in PowerShell:

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> $csv | Select-Object FAILED

FAILED      
------      
0
0
0

PS ..\pwsh> $csv | Where-Object H1 -EQ Dirs

H1       : Dirs
Total    : 332
Copied   : 332
Skipped  : 332
Mismatch : 0
FAILED   : 0
Extras   : 0
```

Regex details can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/miBU2f/1.